# How to access button in textbox?

Tags: c#, button, windows-phone-8, textbox

I have a windows phone application like the following. There are two button in textbox. When user click "beyazbtn", I want it to be collapsed and "saribtn" which was collapsed to be visible. I could make two eventhandlers that handle click for both of the buttons but when I try to make another one collapsed, I awared that I can not access either beyazbtn or saribtn variables in C# code. How can I access them?

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="31*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="21*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <es:RegularPolygon Fill="#FFF4F4F5" InnerRadius="0.47211" PointCount="5" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" UseLayoutRounding="False" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Margin="0,11,0,10" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle2" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <es:RegularPolygon Fill="#FFFFBA02" InnerRadius="0.47211" PointCount="5" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" UseLayoutRounding="False"/>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="TextBoxControlTemplate1" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Grid>
            <Button x:Name="beyazbtn" Content="" Height="52" Margin="374,0,10,10" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="beyazbtn_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="saribtn" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="52" Margin="374,0,0,10" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle2}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="52" Click="saribtn_Click"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Loaded` event in the `Grid` of `TextBoxControlTemplate1`. Then save the button reference.

```
Button beyazbtn, saribtn;
private void Grid_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    beyazbtn = ((Grid)sender).Children[0] as Button;
    saribtn = ((Grid)sender).Children[1] as Button;
}
```